# Image not displayed with MudImage

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I'm using MudBlazor in my Blazor WASM webapp and I'm trying to add an image like they show in the documentation. My image is located in the `/Images` folder. The component where I'm trying to show the image is in `/Shared/Components`.

```
<MudImage Src="/Images/logo_v4_2_190.png" Width="160" Height="190" Alt="MyApp" Elevation="25" Class="rounded-lg" />
```

I've tried to use the path without the first slash `Images/logo_v4_2_190.png` and the result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In Blazor WASM - put the image in wwwroot folder.

Comment: OK, I wouldn't have figured that out. It works. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blazor WebAssembly - keep images in the wwwroot folder.